# ShareKit Api Change

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sharekit

I am trying to change ShareKit API code of attachment to this code below:

```
dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"%@\",\"href\"
:\"%@\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://example.com/example.png\"
,\"href\": \"http://example.com/\"}]} ",item.title == nil ? SHKEncodeURL(item.URL) 
SHKEncode(item.title),SHKEncodeURL(item.URL)];
```

Xcode Keeps telling me prefix error.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an colon in the three-way conditional;

The original code looks like this:

```
dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"%@\",\"href\"
:\"%@\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://example.com/example.png\"
,\"href\": \"http://example.com/\"}]} ",item.title == nil ? SHKEncodeURL(item.URL) 
SHKEncode(item.title),SHKEncodeURL(item.URL)];
```

Change it to this

```
dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"%@\",\"href\"
:\"%@\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://example.com/example.png\"
,\"href\": \"http://example.com/\"}]} ",item.title == nil ? SHKEncodeURL(item.URL): 
SHKEncode(item.title),SHKEncodeURL(item.URL)];
```

The error is at the end of the third line.

You should have seen this in the XCode editor, with a little yellow charat under the position where the error is.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry to say, but your code is one big piece of spaghetti code. It is hard to read, prone to mistakes and hard to maintain (not only for you, but for your fellow coders as well).

I'd like to suggest breaking down the code a bit - for example:

```
// one way to define constant strings...
NSString * const kSHKAttachmentTemplateString = @"{\"name\":\"%@\",\"href\":\"%@\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://example.com/example.png\",\"href\":\"http://example.com/\"}]}"

// and another one that uses a #defined constant string at the beginning of header file of .m file
#define SHK_ATTACHMENT_TEMPLATE_STR    @"{\"name\":\"%@\",\"href\":\"%@\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://example.com/example.png\",\"href\":\"http://example.com/\"}]}"

// assuming item is an valid object
NSString *itemTitleOrURL = (item.title == nil) ? SHKEncodeURL(item.URL) : SHKEncode(item.title);

dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:SHK_ATTACHMENT_TEMPLATE_STR, itemTitleOrURL, SHKEncodeURL(item.URL)];
```

Following a readable code style will definitely save you time while solving similar syntax errors.